# Directory Not Found Exception C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file-copying

I am creating the file list of both source & target directory in target location, the requirement is based on the difference of these two files copy only the files that are new from last iteration.

For 1st iteration copy works, next iteration creates a blank diff [Difference] file is created, to handle this I have added if condition where I check length of file and copy them again. But the if condition is not working as per behavior, with length zero it goes to else statement and throws out error with blank file name :

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\interswitch\source\'.
```

Here's the code:

```
 string path = Path.Combine(target_dir, "Diff.txt");

        if (new FileInfo(path).Length == 0)

         {

            foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())

         {
            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(targetinfo.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
         }
       }        

        else

        foreach (string file in File.ReadLines(path))
        {

            {
                string sourceFile   = System.IO.Path.Combine(source_dir, file);
                string destFile     = System.IO.Path.Combine(target_dir, file);
                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
            }


        }
```

Comment: "next iteration creates a blank diff [Difference] file is created"
can you elaborate that sentence? Also an "empty" file does not automatically have length 0, have you tried checking said files length?

Comment: 1st run the diff file will have all contents from source because target is empty, now in next run with no new files added to source and same files in target empty diff file is created. If empty file is of not length Zero , what would be ideal approach to check if file is blank

Comment: ah, so you create a diff file, that means you check for diffs between target and source directory? why do you write them in a file instead of a list and handle it internally? Anyway, "if (new FileInfo(path).Length == 0)" is correct if the file is empty, have you checked the file? Maybe its not completly empty?

Comment: yes I will handle it internally just wanted to log some test cases, the file looks empty in text editor although file size is 1KB, length should return Zero if no strings are there .. not sure if this behavior is true

Comment: Toggle a breakpoint at if (new FileInfo(path).Length == 0)
or do Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo(path).Length); then you will see

Comment: cool .. de-bug gives out the length as 2, as soon I equate value to 2 it works .. still looking for a more cleaner approach

Comment: do you write the diff yourself? post code/ open a new question and we shall find out why its not 0, also i will post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (new FileInfo(path).Length == 0)` 
does not produce 0 apparently, you have to fix that